# Error creating a spatial database. ERROR

Tags: postgis, postgresql, error

I have been trying to get Postgis set up for a while now, I am stuck on one error and have not found a solutions yet. This is on Ubuntu 14.04.1.

I am trying to run:

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis
```

But am getting this error:

```
ERROR: could not load library "/usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/lib/rtpostgis-2.0.so": libgdal1.7.0.so
```

I am taking it's saying I need to get libgdal installed but every thing I have found so far doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Is this a clean install or after an upgrade?

Comment: It was a clean install, but just solved the issue about an hour ago. At some point I had two version of installed and they were conflicting.

Comment: Glad you solved it. I just did a 1,5 to 2.1 upgrade. Major pain, lots of errors.